# PostgreSQL where condition not found for this

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

```
date;intvalue
"2016-12-27";1
"2016-12-27";2
"2016-12-27";3
"2016-12-27";4
"2016-12-28";1
"2016-12-28";2
"2016-12-28";3
"2016-12-28";4
```

In this resultset, who i could in a where condition remove the last's three lines?

If I put `(date!='2016-12-28' and intvalue>1)` then  all rows are removed.. only the first remains..

Should have a way which the where the arguments of 'where clause' can be processed by row and not by column..

Can anyone help me  and give me a tip in this problem?

thanks and sorry my english.

Comment: `where true order by 1,2 limit 5`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is the algorithm. If you need the get just the first 5 rows from the resultset, "limit 5" is good, as @Vao Tsun suggested. But if the resultset can change and you need the get records according to a where clause, depending on your needs you can play with logical operands, e.g.

```
where not (myDate>='2016-12-28' and myInt>1)

where (myDate<'2016-12-28' or myInt=1)

where (myDate<='2016-12-27' or (myDate='2016-12-28' and myInt=1))
```

etc.